# How to determine if an HTTP response is text-like from content type

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am sending a request in NodeJS using the `request` module. I set `encoding:null` so that the response is always a `Buffer`.

Now, from the content-type response header, I decide whether to treat this buffer as image, video or audio. I do this by extracting the first part of the content type header. For example, PNG image has content type as `image/png` and as such the first part is `image`.

However, I could not find a way to predictably determine all genre of text response. For example, json can have a content type as application/json.

I could make a list of keywords to find in the content type value or make a list of content types that I think is text based (but that's too tedious.)

Comment: Did you try `text/plain` content type ?

Comment: That's only for text. I am trying to find a way to determine all text-based content types such as XML, json, HTML, CSV and all such non-binary responses

Comment: You have one option I think, go to [complete list of mimetypes](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html) and extract ones you need.

Comment: Oh no! That's exactly what I was trying to avoid. But seems like it's the only option! Damn its gonna be a long night now.